# Braintree drop-in UI with iOS tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, braintree

I am trying to implement the Braintree drop-in UI in my iOS app.
I am presenting the drop-in ui from one of the views that are controller by a Tab Bar Controller. My problems start when I try switching tabs while the drop-in is presented. The view "behind" the drop-in ui goes black and doesn't come back until I close the drop-in.
I imagine the best solution to this would be to close the drop-in when user switches to another tab but I can't figure out how to implement it.

To present the drop-in I am using the code from Braintree docs which is:

```
func showDropIn(clientTokenOrTokenizationKey: String) {
    let request =  BTDropInRequest()
    let dropIn = BTDropInController(authorization: clientTokenOrTokenizationKey, request: request)
    { (controller, result, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("ERROR")
        } else if (result?.isCancelled == true) {
            print("CANCELLED")
        } else if let result = result {
            // Use the BTDropInResult properties to update your UI
            // result.paymentOptionType
            // result.paymentMethod
            // result.paymentIcon
            // result.paymentDescription
        }
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    self.present(dropIn!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The problem with this implementation is that I do not have a global method to dismiss this view. The docs however do not offer a different implementation option.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since nobody answered my question I asked the technical support. They didn't offer a great fix but more of a walkaround. This implementation fixes it:

```
self.tabBarController?.present(dropIn!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Instead of just

```
self.present(dropIn!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope that helps somebody someday :)